# Docker daemon fails

Tags: docker, daemon, ubuntu-14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on Dell Latitude E6430 and have installed docker.io package. Now whenever I restart my system, first docker command fails with message

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?
```

Hence to fix this i run below command and daemon works like charm

```
ps -ef |grep docker
kill -9 *pid found* | rm /var/run/docker.pid
```

I have check previous questions and none answer this behaviour
Any idea why is breaking ?

Comment: you can get this messsage if you are no longer connected to the Internet, but I guess you checked it.

Comment: Is your user part of the `docker` group?

Comment: I am checking using root user

Comment: Still experiencing the problem?